# Why is ioctl() not blocking?

Tags: process, pipe, ioctl

I have written code for passing file descriptors between unrelated processes using streams.
The server should wait for the client to send a file descriptor.
Here is the server code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>   
#include <sys/stat.h>  
#include <fcntl.h>  
#include <stropts.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <errno.h>  
#include <unistd.h>  

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    int fd;  
    int pipefd[2];  
    pipe(pipefd);  
    close(pipefd[1]);  
    recvfd(pipefd[0]);  
    return 0;
}

void recvfd(int p)  
{
    struct strrecvfd rfdbuf;  
    struct stat statbuf;   
    int i;  
    i=ioctl(p, I_RECVFD, &rfdbuf);  
    printf("errno=%d\n",errno);  
    printf("recvfd=%d\n", rfdbuf.fd);  
}
```

But I receive the error number 9 - Bad file descriptor.

Comment: What operating system are you using? It is difficult to answer a question about an OS call without knowing the OS.

Comment: Why do you think that it is returning an error?  This code does not even check the ioctl return value.  If it is not -1, errno is not changed and could have a value from a prior system call (e.g. in the dynamic loader or startup routines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention what OS you are running. I_RECVFD is part of the STREAMS extensions which are normally only present in System V based Unixy operating systems (AIX and Solaris for example). Others, like Linux and BSD, do not support it and probably never will as Posix now has an alternative using sendmsg() and recvmsg().

I'm afraid that I don't know why Linux has #defines I_RECVFD if it does not support it.

Comment: I had to use ioctl() with fifos (and not pipes) and like you said, it does not work on Linux but works on Solaris.

Answer (score 2):

NB: the question has been extensively modified since this answer was written.

---

Where to begin?

- `main()` returns an `int`.
- `pipefd` is not initialized.
- You close a random file descriptor.
- You call `recvfd()` on another random file descriptor.
- You don't return a value from `main()`.
- You don't use the `#define` value.
- You don't show the `#include` files needed to make this compile.
- Unused variable `fd`.
- Unused variable `statbuf`.
- Unchecked return value `i`.

Basic problem - use of uninitialized variables.

Subsidiary problem - limited error checking.

---

Additional problem: conceptually, you want a server that can be passed a file descriptor.  You need that server to be reading from a file descriptor that other (unrelated) processes can create.  You will need to look at the manuals rather carefully, but will probably need the server listening on a Unix-domain socket, or perhaps reading on a (named) FIFO.  Other programs can then open the socket or FIFO and send their own file descriptor to the server.

Comment: Technically, it's ok to omit the return type from main() (but for main _only_), in which case `int' is assumed.  Similarly, it's ok to omit the return statement from main (again, main _only_), in which case there is an implicit 'return 0'.  It's still bad practice, though.

Comment: Not in C99, which is the current C standard.  There are no 'implicit int' return types etc in C99.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the actual code ?
Cause nowhere do you create or receive a valid filedescriptor.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `pipefd`! Missing a

```
pipe(pipefd);
```

line before the `close` call...?